# Manifold and scalar product defined as an integral

Tags: analysis

Let define $B=\{x_1^2+...+x_n^2 \leq 0\}$ with boundary $S=\{|{x^2}|=1\}$. Then let $X=\{f\in C^2(B):f|_{S}\equiv0\}$ be a space with scalar product given as follows: $$(f,g)=\int_B fg\ d\lambda_n\ .$$ Show, that $(\Delta f,f)\leq 0$ with equality only when $f \equiv 0$.

I tried to prove the above relation, but to no avail so far. Any ideas?

Comment: $\Delta$ is the Laplacian, no?

Comment: Yes, it's Laplacian

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** apply [Green's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green.27s_first_identity) (noting the zero boundary condition) to find
$$
(\Delta f,f) = \int_B \Delta f \cdot f\,d\lambda_n = -\int_B |\nabla f|^2\, d \lambda_n
$$